# can we charge a neutral glass rod by touching it with charged glass rod?

Tags: electrostatics

Can we charge a neutral glass rod by touching it with charged glass rod?Can we charge similar objects by contact of which one is charged and other neutral?

Comment: Charging by contact can be caused by adhesion (read cause part of triboelectric effect [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect)). As you are speaking about contact electrification by similar surfaces there will be no triboelectric effect. Electrification can also be caused by cohesion due to intrinsic properties, like in mercury. I don't think so, electrification due to cohesive force can take place here. Leaving the above two effects you can even expect two bodies to get charged via contact, if they are metals. As glass is not metal, it is also not possible.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can. Your charged rods have potential difference, and no matter what they are made of they have finite resitance, now what type of charging you wish to achieve may or may not be possible, for example a particular charge in a particular spot or uniformly spread all over that would depend on your skills and apparatus and time required.

For example if the charge and potential difference is low, and resistance of your rod is pretty high it may take days or weeks till the charge gets transferred, and after even more days it will spread uniformly because of finite resitance of the rods.

And yes ofcourse we can charge objects of same nature by a charged one of same nature, we do that **all** the time in case of metals.